# gcloud function php post size issue

Tags: php, function, google-cloud-functions

I have a gcloud function in PHP that receives a json object.
Inside my function, I read the json object like this: file_get_contents('php://input').

This works for me when the json object that I receive in the function is less than 16KB, but when the json object is greater than 16KB it returns empty.

Comment: It occurs because of payload being received by PHP function is over 16kb. If the data is smaller than 16kb, there is no issue. Try to apply compression (like gzip) to make the data "smaller" prior to sending and then on the receiving end, it can be decomposed to make it "larger". In this case the compression and decompression is completely handled by the application code and not infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

There is no code, neither client- nor server-side ...

You might be sending as `enctype="multipart/form-data"`
? https://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input
While `file_get_contents('php://input')` is questionable by itself.

Instead use the default method signature, which provides `ServerRequestInterface $request`:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
...

public static function on_https( ServerRequestInterface $request ): ResponseInterface {

    $params = $request->getQueryParams();
    $body = $request->getBody();

    $body->rewind(); // or $body->seek(0);
    $bodyText = $body->getContents();
    $data = json_decode($bodyText);

    return (new Response())
        ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
        ->withBody(Utils::streamFor(json_encode($data)))
        ->withStatus(200);
}
```

Just recently pushed a template composer [project](https://github.com/syslogic/php-cloudfunctions-quickstart) to GitHub, based on the documentation. Not exactly certain about `$body->rewind()`, that's only required for streams (it may return `string` already). This requires `"guzzlehttp/psr7": "^2.1.0"`. Also see: [What is PSR-7 and how to use it?](https://www.dotkernel.com/how-to/what-is-psr-7-and-how-to-use-it/)

Comment: this in my code in gcloud function

<?php

print file_get_contents('php://input');

?>


i send content in raw

Comment: how can i call that funcion?

Comment: i use file_get_contents('php://input') localy and works good, but in gcloud functions only works if content is less than 16KB