# Google Cloud Functions PHP 7.4 ignore HTTP requests body longer than around 16000 characters

Tags: php, json, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, http-post

this question could be a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71013872/gcloud-function-php-post-size-issue)

I use a HTTP POST request to send a JSON text to my Google Cloud Function running PHP. Here is the example of the codes:

```
<?php
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Google\CloudFunctions\FunctionsFramework;
FunctionsFramework::http('insertbdd', 'insertbdd');

function insertbdd(ServerRequestInterface $request)
{
    $body = $request->getBody()->getContents();
    $size = (int) $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'];
    fwrite($log, "body : ".$body."\n");
    fwrite($log, "size : ".$size."\n");
    if (!empty($body)) {
        // save to database
    } else {
        die()
    }
}
```

When I try to pass a JSON file of which length is shorter than about 16000 characters, everything is fine, but if the size of the file surpass 16000 characters, I got nothing, the body is empty and the CONTENT_LENGTH is 0.

I am pretty sure the problem is on the receiver side, as I tried to send the JSON by PHP Curl, Postman and the test of Google Cloud Function.

In the other question [Sandeep Vokkareni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18265702/sandeep-vokkareni) mentioned that the reason is the payload of PHP function being larger than 16kb. However I couldn't find any information about this 16kb payload online. Any link please ?

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem using Cloud Function gen1 with php 7.4 and I couldn't find any way to get it work.

I tested with Cloud Function gen2 with php8.1 and **it's works**.